# VSCode debugging is not working by click F5

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to create new WebAPI project by using dotnet CLI commend. I created and tried to run by clicking F5, it is loading and debugging symbol also came. After some time it is stopping it.
I installed debugger for chrome also. It generates launch.json file too. But unable to start debugging it.

Up to below line it is debugging it.

Debugger console i got below log:

> You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
>   Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software to help you develop and test your applications.

I am using below software:

- Windows 7
- VSCode 1.44.0
- node 12.16.71
- npm 6.13.4

When i start run by CLI then it is running it. I want to debug my application from VSCode.

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved my issue. Due to different sdk software. Mine system is 64bit OS but i was installed 86bit sdk. So that reason it was not working. Issue got resolved after i installed 64bit sdk. Thank you.